# C++ "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" error

Tags: c++

I was trying to do some C++ homework for beginner programming classes, but I've come across a problem in my code. The homework states:

> Create a program that asks the user for 2 integer numbers, then indicate if the first number is a multiple of the second. (using the conditional operator to choose within two strings and show the necessary one based off of the answer)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n1;
    int n2;
    cout << "Enter a number: \n";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Enter another number:\n";
    cin >> n2;
   
   
    int residue = n1 % n2;                                      //Remains of the division
    cout << residue;
    bool isMultiple = residue == 0;
    string r1 = (n1 << "is a multiple of " << n2);
    string r2 = ( n1 << "is not a multiple of " << n2);
    string ans = isMultiple ? r1 : r2;
    cout << ans;
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting

[image: error code with lines and error]

Comment: You seem to think that `(n1 << "is a multiple of " << n2)` will create a string.  It does not.

Comment: See the OUTPUT tab beside the PROBLEMS tab? I'm betting it contains the build output as text. Not only will this be easier to put in a Stack Overflow question, but it will be more useful for future askers with a similar problem because text is a lot easier to search than an image  AND the full build output often contains more information and useful hints.

Comment: You can't build a string like that.  You can do something like `std::to_string(n1) + " is a... " + std::to_string(n2)`

Comment: Recommendation : if you write less code at a time you'll find you won't repeat mistakes as often. Write a few lines, compile and test. Only add more when the code compiles and behaves exactly as expected. This isn't as important with a little tiny program like this, but comes in really really handy as your programs gain complexity.

Comment: A good online reference is cppreference.com. I see smorgasborgas has already suggested std::to_string. You can find more information here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Answer (score 3):

In these statements:

```cpp
string r1 = (n1 << "is a multiple of " << n2);
string r2 = ( n1 << "is not a multiple of " << n2);
```

`n1` and n2 are `int` variables.  So, for `r1`, you are calling the [bitwise `<<` left shift operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic), first with an `int` for the left operand and a `const char[]` (string literal) for the right operand, and then a 2nd time with the result on the left and an `int` on the right.  But you simply can't shift an `int` by a string literal, that will not work, which is why you get a compiler error.

And then you are doing the same for `r2`, so you get the same error for it, too.

You appear to be trying to store *formatted output* into your `string` variables. You can't use `<<` to assign a `std::string` like that. Use a [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

...

ostringstream oss;
oss << n1 << " is a multiple of " << n2;
string r1 = oss.str();

oss.str("");
oss << n1 << " is not a multiple of " << n2;
string r2 = oss.str();
```

Otherwise, convert the `int`s to `std::string` using [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) (or equivalent), and then use the [`+` concatenation operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) to join them, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
using namespace std;

...

string r1 = to_string(n1) + " is a multiple of " + to_string(n2);
string r2 = to_string(n1) + " is not a multiple of " + to_string(n2);
```

Or, use [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) (or the [{fmt} library](https://fmt.dev)), eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <format> // or <fmt/core.h>
using namespace std;
//using namespace fmt;

...

string r1 = format("{} is a multiple of {}", n1, n2);
string r2 = format("{} is not a multiple of {}", n1, n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your context the << operator would work for streams (like std::out), not for strings.
What you want is to concatenate the strings and the simplest way here is to replace 2 your strings with the:

```
string r1 = std::to_string(n1) + "is a multiple of " + std::to_string(n2);
string r2 = std::to_string(n1) + "is not a multiple of " + std::to_string(n2);
```

Don't forget to

```
#include <string>
```

at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

By adding #include <string> to your file, you'll easily be able to concatenate integers with strings. I've made slight changes to your code which accomplishes this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n1;
    int n2;
    cout << "Enter a number: \n";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Enter another number:\n";
    cin >> n2;


    int residue = n1 % n2;                                      //Remains of the division
    cout << residue;
    bool isMultiple = residue == 0;
    string r1 = (to_string(n1) + " is a multiple of " + to_string(n2));
    string r2 = (to_string(n1) + " is not a multiple of " + to_string(n2));
    string ans = isMultiple ? r1 : r2;
    cout << ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the strings completely wrong - it just is not C++ code.

Also, you would not need to waste resources in run-time for creating the both strings since you guaranteedly use only one of them.

You can use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
    

int main() {

    using namespace std;

    int n1;
    cout << "Enter a number: \n";
    cin >> n1;

    int n2;
    cout << "Enter another number:\n";
    cin >> n2;
   
    int residue = n1 % n2;

    cout << residue;

    bool isMultiple = (residue == 0);

    if (isMultiple) {

        cout << n1 << " is a multiple of " << n2;
        
    } else {

        cout << n1 << " is not a multiple of " << n2;

    }    

}
```